# CSS Hiding and showing content

Tags: css, materialize

I am tring to hide the content of a Div when hovering/selecting another. I have put together a rough codeply to illustrate what im trying to achieve.

Essentially i need the initial text to not display once other pictures are being hovered or tapped if on mobile but to obviously display again if that picture is hovered over or tapped again..

http://codeply.com/go/EsrJ8Rl1P8

Iv'e been reading about css selectors but i just can't figure this out.

Thanks.

Comment: Please bring your "*[MCVE]*" code into the question, don't expect us to follow links blindly around the internet in order to help, should that external resource ever be moved, deleted or reorganised in any way then the link becomes entirely useless to those viewing your question in future.

Comment: You need javascript or jquery to achieve this. Also there are few issue with your code.

Comment: @DavidThomas is correct, an external link may change, rendering the question useless for future searches. Also flagged comment as rude/offensive.

Answer (score 0):

Although CSS syntax can only select child elements and subsequent sibling elements, you *can* take advantage of the flexbox attribute `order`, to display an element first - even though it's actually a subsequent sibling element.

**e.g.**

```css
body {
display: flex;
}

section {
width: 160px;
height: 160px;
margin-right: 40px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
order: 1;
}

.initial {
order: 0;
}

.icon {
display:block;
margin: 10px auto;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
}

p, section:hover ~ section p {
display: none;
}

.initial p, section:hover p {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div class="icon" />Hover over me</div>
<p>When this text is visible, I need the others to vanish!</p>
</section>

<section>
<div class="icon" />Hover over me</div>
<p>When this text is visible, I need the others to vanish!</p>
</section>

<section class="initial">
<div class="icon" />Hover over me</div>
<p>This is visible initially</p>
</section>
```